# The correct way of assigning props for child component

Tags: reactjs

I wonder which way of assigning props which are going to be passed to a child component is correct (both in React correctness (syntax, common practices) and also efficiency), and if there is a much better way of achieveing this, please let me know.

So, currently in my project I have a parent component which gets some data and pass it to a child (I'm actually going to encapsulate it even further and have a child gets the data, but I'm still curious about the proper solution).

My code is something like this:

```
class Dashboard extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            a: 'foo',
            b: 'bar',
            stats: {
                c: 'c',
                d: 'd'
            }
        }
    }

    someFunction = () => {

    }

  render() {
    let childData = this.state.stats
    childData.function = this.someFunction

    return (
      <div>
        <ChildComponent {...childData}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

As you may see I assign all the data for the child component inside `render()`, and there is no specific reason for it really. I've seen this on one video on Lynda, while watching React stuff and I liked it. I believe I could just do this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        a: 'foo',
        b: 'bar',
        stats: {
            c: 'c',
            d: 'd'
        }
    }

    let childData = this.state.stats
    childData.function = this.someFunction 
}
```

I would like to know which of those, if any, is more "react" way of doing this, or is there a better way? Am I right thinking that there may be a performance issue, with those data being assigned every single time the parent component is rendered? If so, is this going to be minimized if I move the logic to constructor, so the assignment happens only once?

Thanks for help!

Comment: What are you building and for what target(s)? knowing this will provide us more info to help you hit the right performance

Comment: @azium it's going to be a website displaying real-time changes in the physical assembly process. Changes are being sent from the backend running on NodeJS, via websockets. Both front-end and back-end are run on the Windows-powered PC. The specific page (from the question) will be displayed on large screen tv, through raspberryPi, hence I'm trying to make it as performance-light/correct as possible. I've been told at wok that raspberryPi may struggle showing pages in React because of the rendering, not sure how much truth is in that though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I would say neither of those options are "the React way". Taking your exact component I would say the following is most common:

```
class Dashboard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      a: 'foo',
      b: 'bar',
      stats: {
        c: 'c',
        d: 'd',
      },
    }
  }

  someFunction = () => {}

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ChildComponent
          stats={this.state.stats}
          handleSomeEvent={this.someFunction}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

However that is only the most common way pre version 16.8. The most common way now would be this instead:

```
function Dashboard() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    a: 'foo',
    b: 'bar',
    stats: {
      c: 'c',
      d: 'd',
    },
  })

  const someFunction = () => {}

  return (
    <div>
      <ChildComponent 
        stats={state.stats} 
        handleSomeEvent={someFunction} 
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: I used this method few times throughout the project and what I found out is that when you have multiple functions/variables you want to pass to children it can cause slightly long code (stack). Then I thought using spread operator and assignment (as I did above) will make the code look "prettier". Althogh, if it's the most appropriate way of doing it, I will have to change over. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be a correct way.

The expensive part is manipulating the DOM. The performance hit is mitigated by React and you can go a long way to help by using `PureComponent` or the `memo` function to declare your child component.

Pure components and memoized functional components do a shallow compare and are only re-rendered if the shallow compare fails. The shallow compare is done in `shouldComponentUpdate` for `PureComponent`. You can also implement your own `shouldComponentUpdate` function in a "normal" `Component`. If this returns false your child component will not re-render.

So to reiterate. 
Does assigning properties to child components create overhead - Yes, however, this is not a lot compared to the other overhead your application will face.

As for a non-React specific answer. Code should be readable and understandable. Creating an intermediate object just to destructure it does not make a lot of sense.

So this:

```
let childData = this.state.stats
childData.function = this.someFunction
```

Is not really needed. Rather assign directly to your component

Comment: Thanks for the answer with detailed exlpanation. By saying "assign directly", do you mean using the method displayed by @azium below?

Comment: yeah, as @azium has it.